# Converting from ASP to PHP

Tags: php, asp-classic

How do I convert this line of code which is in ASP to PHP?

```
<INPUT type="hidden" name="<%= NAME_KEY%>" value="<%= VALUE %>">
```

Comment: what so ASPish is there?

Comment: Sorry I'm still learning. .specifically this part: `name="<%= NAME_KEY%>"` or does it remain the same in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<INPUT type="hidden" name="<?php echo $NAME_KEY; ?>" value="<?php echo $VALUE; ?>">
```

Comment: Make sure $NAME_KEY and $VALUE are set. No problem. Have fun! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo "<INPUT type=\"hidden\" name=\"$NAME_KEY\" value=\"$VALUE\">" ?>
```

This presupposes that you convert your NAME_KEY variable to a PHP variable named $NAME_KEY and VALUE to $VALUE.

Note that the only real difference between this solution and @Time Machine's is that in his you go into and out of PHP 'mode', and in mine you stay in PHP 'mode' but you have to escape your quotes.

An important note regarding PHP!  When you use echo, there's a big difference between wrapping the guts in double-quotes and wrapping them in single-quotes.  Single-quotes takes everything within literally, and doesn't evaluate any variables contained therein.  With double-quotes, your variables are evaluated.

In PHP, variables start with '$'.

I hope this helps!